# Spring boot - boostrap pagination no carga estilo de los botones

Tags: java, html, css, web, spring

Estoy aprendiendo spring boot y agregue una paginacion con boostrap la cosa es que el estilo de los botones no carga. solo carga cuando hago click sobre alguno de los botones y carga el estilo de solo un boton. al agregar la clase page-link a las etiquetas  y  la enumeración se muestra de manera vertical y no horizontal.

por alguna razon no me deja agregar todo el codigo fuente porque dice que la publicacion es mayormente codigo.

[image: DE esta forma]

este es mi codigo html:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Clientes</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>APELLIDO</th>
        <th>EDAD</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <th>ACCIONES</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="cliente : ${clientes}">
        <td th:text="${cliente.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${cliente.nombre}"></td>
        <td th:text="${cliente.apellido}"></td>
        <td th:text="${cliente.edad}"></td>
        <td th:text="${cliente.email}"></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-secondary" th:href="@{/clientes/delete/{id}(id=${cliente.id})}" onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de que quieres eliminar este cliente?');">Eliminar</a> || <a class="btn btn-secondary" th:href="@{/update/{id}(id=${cliente.id})}" target="_blank">Editar</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<footer class="panel-footer">
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        Total Items [[${totalItems}]] : Page [[${currentPage}]] of [[${totalPages}]]

        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item">
                <a  class="page-link" th:if="${currentPage > 1}" th:href="@{/clientes/page/1}">First</a>
                <span class="page-link" th:unless="${currentPage > 1}">First</span>
            </li>

            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" th:if="${currentPage > 1}" th:href="@{'/clientes/page/' + ${currentPage - 1}}">Previous</a>
                <span class="page-link" th:unless="${currentPage > 1}">Previous</span>
            </li>

            <li class="page-item">
                <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}">
                    <a class="page-link" th:if="${i != currentPage}" th:href="@{'/clientes/page/' + ${i}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                    <span class="page-link" th:unless="${i != currentPage}">[[${i}]]</span>
                </span>
            </li>

            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/clientes/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}}">Next</a>
                <span class="page-link" th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Next</span>
            </li>

            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/clientes/page/' + ${totalPages}}">Last</a>
                <span class="page-link" th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Last</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar el estilo `page-link` a cada anchor. El único que está agregado es el del botón "First", y por eso se ve.
Además este estilo u otro es necesario agregarlo en todos los `span` anotados con `unless`.

[Aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-conditionals) te dejo una referencia para repasar el uso de condicionales con Thymeleaf.

En el caso de los números de página te salen agrupados en forma vertical porque *todos* están dentro de un `page-item`, cuando *cada uno* es un ítem. Deberías buscar que te queden elementos de este tipo

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
```

Tal cual está explicado [en la documentación oficial.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/)

Para esto tienes que encerrar el `page-item` de los números de página dentro del `span` de esta forma:

```
<span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" th:if="${i != currentPage}" th:href="@{'/clientes/page/' + ${i}}">[[${i}]]</a>
        <span class="page-link" th:unless="${i != currentPage}">[[${i}]]</span>
    </li>
</span>
```

Comment: si pero esque cuando agrego page-link a cada atributo <a> por alguna razon los numeros cargan de forman vertical

Comment: Eso no es lo que preguntaste. Fijate de agregar la el código fuente de la página completa para poder ver el problema.

Comment: ya agregue todo el codigo fuente

Comment: @sumrandom1989 si te sirvió esta respuesta, marcala así el resto de los usuarios que después puedan tener un problema similar saben que esta es la forma de resolver el problema.